# Why are my Nav bar tags not incorporating the CSS? Was working yesterday, so I broke it?

Tags: css, navigation, navigationbar

Using w3.school's example, I had navigation buttons working.  Now they incorporation a class I have in the CSS file, but not modifications on the tags.

I did a bunch of changes since yesterday, I'll go into below in case it's a clue.

For testing, I moved the CSS into the top of the same file.  There's a navbar class that I created in the .css file that appears to be impacting.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="/NavigationBarStyles.css" type="text/css"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="/test.css" type="text/css"> <style> ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden; }

li {
    float: left; }

a:link, a:visited {
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #98bf21;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase; }

a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: #7A991A; } </style>
   </style>

   </head>

   <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000">
```

---

Here's the list items I want converted to a horizonatal nav bar:

```
    <td width="71%"> 
  <div id="nav"> 
 <ul  class="NavButtonsOriginal">
 <li><a href="http://www.genafter.com/index.php/">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="http://www.genafter.com/GenAfterComing.php/">Upcoming<br>Events</a></li>
(etc.)
</ul>
```

```
</td>
```

I switched all files to .php extension so I can pull the navbar.html file into all of them with an (include) php statement.  I left the navbar an html.

Currently I took the nav id off the CSS in the file.  I was testing here without id=nav" and put it in only to show it here.  I also tried class="nav".  (I had put .nav at the front of tags that were being modified.)  In the file I have  tags but it was the same once removed.

It's in DW and there's not yellow tag mismatch complaints.

I'm running mostly in DW and on my local machine into the browser.  But none of this is php code, so it doesn't matter that I'm not on the server side?

When I put the address straight into the URL bar and everything has been uploaded, the results:
[enter link description here](http://genafterdc.com/NavigationBar.php)

I'm completely baffled.  It has to be some simple setting, that I have no idea of.  I'm almost done with the whole site and it's needed immediately for our coming stuff.... so this is the last highly necessary piece.

Thank you so much for helping!

## ==============================

Now it's working!

The links from that list were in error (all missing the dc in genafterdc).  They were giving a 404 not found.  I just corrected them.   I noticed too that I have a .html and a .php navigationbar file which are the same and both were giving the non-css impacting response. So that doesn't appear to be it.

Using the PHP file it's working now.  Can it be that if the href's addresses are wrong the .css doesn't modify the tags?  That's not logical.  What caused it to now work?  So I know for the next time it stops.

Thanks for reading through all this!

=====
Came back to post that I took the CSS out of the same file and left it only in the .css file and it's still working.  Only thing I changed is the genafter to genafterdc in all my links.

Comment: http://genafterdc.com/NavigationBar.php that's the link.  I can't seem to edit and add it to the question.

Comment: To clarify this paragraph that I wrote above: "Currently I took the nav id off the CSS in the file. I was testing here without id=nav" and put it in only to show it here. I also tried class="nav". (I had put .nav at the front of tags that were being modified.) In the file I have tags but it was the same once removed."  What I mean is that I had added a class to the css file.  I also had the css that's posted here in that file.  At one point I added .nav in front of every tag, then said id="nav" or class="nav".  (It was working).  I took it out for testing and to post here.

Comment: Replace all your `.nav` to `#nav` from `NavigationBarStyles.css`  as you have used `<div id="nav">` .

Comment: I had class="nav" originally.  It was working.  Still had class and it stopped working.  However, knowing what's id and what's class is good for me to know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your using a class in your css `.nav` but your using a id in your html change the class to an id in your css `#nav`

Comment: i didn't see any `.nav` class in css

Comment: I have just changed the id to a class in your html and it's displaying the correct navigation.

Comment: It had nothing to do with the nav because I took the nav out of the css everywhere and out of the navigationbar files.  Problem existed anyway.  And Now it's gone after I corrected the links in the unordered list.  Makes no sense.

Comment: @Aaron - that's because of coincidental timing.  By the point that you did that, the site had refreshed and was working for me too.  ...unless you tested it one way, made change and immediately it worked??  I'd be curious if that was the case.  BTW, as I said in the question, the nav line wasn't even in when it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the person who asked this question.  I'm quite sure it's a refresh, caching issue by the server.  Or the loads to the server aren't working correctly.

Sometimes old versions appear, other times new.  It's a mix of random timing for when the old appears.  Sometimes it's after the new has posted and I've loaded the new.

Notably:  It's obvious the .css file needs to be uploaded for the tag modification to be implemented, while the longer line of .css in the file  with a full class setup got implemented immediately every time even when not uploaded to the server.  No idea why these would be different, but it's a  consistent pattern.

There were old .css styling reappearing, after it's already brought new up.  So I'm not sure what cacheing is happening  & when.  It may be specific to my website provider's tools.

It's definitely not the .nav issue because I as I said in the question, I didn't have the .nav in while running the tests.  (Though those comments did answer another question for me on .css syntax (#id vs .class ) that I was puzzled about.)

Thanks for being here and letting me know what you thought.  It at the least verified it wasn't something basic I was missing.  And kept me sane while at a frustrating point.

Website is up and running with it working including the paypal and input forms.

Comment: I appreciate the efforts other posts made to help and it did help to have a place to think this through.  Unfortunately they were focused on something thing I posted here but said was -not- in the current code that still had the problem.  So their solutions were to something that wasn't the problem.  So I'm picking this as the answer, since it's the actual solution to the original problem.  Is there a way I can give the two posters points for their assistance?